# RoboTextView ellipsize adds more text after the "..."

Tags: android, android-layout

I use the following `RoboTextView` xml declaration:

```
<com.package.utils.RobotoTextView 
      android:id="@+id/ttli_small_desc"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
      android:textSize="12dp"
      android:paddingBottom="6dp"
      android:maxLines="5"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:textColor="@color/selectable_text_black_to_white"
      bit:fontType="light"/>
```

It is a custom view object, but I've tested it with a standard `TextView` and the same problem occurs. The only thing this custom view does is allow me to use RobotoLight font. A bit outdated of a technique now but it's there so I use it.

Anyways what I'd expect is a maximum of 5 lines which should look like this

```
word words words
words words words
word word words
words word
words words words...
```

But here is what I'm getting:

[image: bad]

Basically it ellipsizes the text, but then just picks right back up afterwards. I've played around with `singleLine=false` and other random attributes trying to fix it but I've struck out so far. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!